# adding users to firebase cloud firestore

Tags: flutter

trying to create an user using firebase sdk, the firebase authetication have created the user but the newly created user is not linked to my cloud firestore, i can't find where the error is coming from i've equall add network access and internet access to all my manfifest file too

```
 void _submitAuthForm(
      String email, String password, String username, bool isLogin) async {
    UserCredential authResult;
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      if (isLogin) {
        authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
      } else {
        authResult = await _auth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
            .then((value) async {
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('accounts')
              .doc(value.user?.uid)
              .set({'email': email, 'username': username});
        }) as UserCredential;

        // await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        //     .collection('accounts')
        //     .doc(authResult.user?.uid)
        //     .set({'email': email, 'username': username});
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {
      var message = 'An error occured, please check your credential';
      if (err.message != null) {
        message = err.message!;
      }
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
      ));
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go to the FireStore database and create a collection called "users". You will also have to get the cloud_firestore package. From here, you can make some kind of callback to create user docs in the collection. For example, if you want to have each user have a unique id and save their display name (if they registered with one) saved in the doc, you can write and call this function after the user has registerd successfully.

```
Future<void> addUserDataToFireStore() async {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  if (uid != null) {
    users.doc(uid).set({
      'userId': uid,
      'email': currentUser!.email,
      'username': currentUser!.username,
    });
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Let me know if that helps or need anything else.